# Storybook typescript mock redux store

Tags: typescript, react-redux, storybook

So I am attempting to follow this tutorial from storybook:

https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/intro-to-storybook/react/en/screen/

To be able to make it possible to display a page in storybook. In it it tells you to mock out redux like so:

```
// A super-simple mock of a redux store
const store = {
  getState: () => {
    return {
      tasks: TaskListStories.Default.args.tasks,
    };
  },
  subscribe: () => 0,
  dispatch: action('dispatch'),
};
```

Then you can just wrap the component in . So it seem straighforward enough, however I've not been able to make this work with typescript due to not being able to easily type this. So I have:

```
const state: RootState = { ... }

const store : Store = {
  getState: () => (state),
  dispatch: (x) => x,
  subscribe: (listener) => () => {},
  replaceReducer: (next) => {},
};
```

I get the error "Property '[Symbol.observable]' is missing in type", as I'm not sure how to make a mock implementation of Symbol.observable: Observable.